# JSP compliation error when trying to acess the application in Weblogic 10.3.5

Tags: jsp, weblogic

I am deploying web application on Weblogic 10.3.5. Application is deployed successfully but I am getting below error when I am trying to access the application

```
Root cause of ServletException. org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: JSPException including path '/WEB-INF/layout/menu.jsp'. at
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:680) at 
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:633) at 
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:322) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262) 
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace Caused By: 
org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: JSPException including path '/WEB-INF/layout/menu.jsp'. at 
org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:232) at 
org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:105) at 
org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96) at 
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.UntypedAttributeRenderer.write(UntypedAttributeRenderer.java:61) at 
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:103) 
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace Caused By: 
weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP /WEB-INF/layout/menu.jsp menu.jsp:16:38: Syntax error in expression. Encountered "(". Expected one of : "}", ".", "[", ">", "gt", "<", "lt", ">=", "ge", "<=", "le", "==", "eq", "!=", "ne", "&&", "and", "||", "or", "*", "+", "-", "?", "/", "div", "%", "mod",
```

Also I tried to put `el-api 2.2`, `jasper-el-6.0.33.jar`, `el-imp 2.2` jar. I also add `context-param` entry in `web.xml` but still it is not working.

I am trying to deploy the application on Weblogic 10.3.5 running on Linux